# Status code 404: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, access-token, api-design, azure-api-apps

I've deployed an API project (.NET Core app 2.1) to Azure, and when I try to call the resource/endpoint I get
status code 404:
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I recently changed the resource/endpoint to accept 2 url parameters. Before that it had only 1, and it worked fine. I'm sending an access token as string in the second parameter, and I've noticed that if I just replace the token, which is quite long, with a short string value, I don't get this error. If the value gets too long, I get the error.

Could a too long URL query parameter value cause this error?
Are access tokens not recommended to be sent as query parameters, even if it is HTTPS?

Comment: Hi, Morten. Is my answer useful to you? Do you need further help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How long is the token length? If query parameter strings too long,it 
will definitely appear this error.
You can refer to this URL [Get Request strings limit](https://helpx.adobe.com/mt/experience-manager/scene7/kb/base/is_protocol-_-forming_is/url-character-limit-get-requests.html)

The token can be sent as a query parameter, and 
it has nothing to do with http or https .I suggest you use Post Request.

Comment: Thanks @jason. I haven't checked the length of the token, but I've succeeded in making a Post request with the same token as a header via Postman.